# @: in a foreach loop doesn't work when it's between tags?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know that `@:` is for   [output  a single line of content containing plain text or unmatched HTML tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c#combining-text-markup-and-code-in-code-blocks);

If so , why do I get an error for :

( *":" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.*)

```
  @foreach (int line in new int[] { 0, 1 })
    {
        <span>
          @: aaaaa
        </span>
    }
```

While this run as expected :

```
@foreach (int line in new int[] { 0, 1 })
{
      @: aaaaa
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@:` is used to mix text within a code block.

When you use the `span` tag or any other html elements, inside a C# code block, you are already mixing HTML tag and razor can properly parse and execute it. When you use `@:` inside an HTML element (non-code block), it is not even valid.

In short, you can use HTML elements inside a code block as wrapper to mix plaintext/html.

```
@foreach (int line in new int[] { 0, 1 })
{
    <div>Hello</div>
}
```

In razor, the `@:` tag produce the same result as the `text` tag when it comes to mixing plain text within a code block. The below will also produce same result as your second code block.

```
@foreach (int line in new int[] { 0, 1 })
{
    <text>aaa533</text>
}
```

Comment: _No need to explicitly use the @: tag_ ------ >No need ? or not allowed ?

Comment: It is not valid.

Comment: `@foreach (int line in new int[] { 0, 1 })

    {
        if (true)
        {
            @: aaaaa
        }


    }`, ---- does work

Comment: The comment you posted and deleted works, because your `if` is starting a code block and you need `@:` to mix plain text inside that.